# How can I publish an int8 array as a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid?

Tags: ros, navigation, c++, occupancy-grid, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ultimately I would like to publish an Eigen matrix as a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid. So I thought it would be a good idea to try first if I can publish an arbitrary int8 array as a map.

To my understanding, the map consists of an int8[] array (cannot post link due to missing karma: docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html). According to (cannot post link due to missing karma: wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields)) an int8 is equivalent to an int8_t in C++. But the following simple code does not work and causes the error below (the code compiles without the last line). What am I missing here? Thanks a lot.

```
nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid map;
map.info.resolution = 1.0;         // float32
map.info.width      = 2;           // uint32
map.info.height     = 2;           // uint32
int8_t a[4] = {100, 100, 50, 0};   // array of int8_t
std::cout << a << std::endl;
map.data = a;
```

Error by the compiler:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘map.nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid_<std::allocator<void> >::data = a’
```

If relevant: I use Hydro on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

---

SOLUTION:

Following the hint, the code below worked for me.

```
int p[] = {100, 100, 50, 0};
std::vector<signed char> a(p, p+4);
map.data = a;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158196/how-can-i-publish-an-int8-array-as-a-nav_msgs/occupancygrid?/) by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the message fields description on how arrays are handled. The data[] is actually a `std::vector`, so you can't initialize `map.data` with a raw array.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on 2014-04-28**:
Perfect. That hint lead me back on the right track. I will post the working code below my original question.